# Two MCU Connected To Same Ethernet Port

Tags: circuit-design, ethernet, texas-instruments

Hello iam a bit stumped with this i have 2 mcu's both MSP432E on the same pcb.I only have one ethernet port but need both MCU's to be connected to the one ethernet port.Can i simply have 2 ethernet transformers,and connect the media side together with there like pins connect so tranformer 1 RX+ pin would have a trace going to transformer 2 RX+ pin?What would be the correct way going about what iam trying to accomplish?Thanks

Comment: No, you can't do that.  This really sounds like a mistaken system architecture - putting MCU's on Ethernet is rarely a good idea.  Likely you should either have one device proxy for both MCUs or replace both with a single more powerful device.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an Ethernet hub. They come in multiple flavors, with different channel counts, different interfaces, integrated PHYs, etc. You'll probably want one with 2 RMII interfaces and 1 PHY.